# Как мне узнать библиотеку которая выдает ошибку в манифесте

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

Пробую собрать apk получаю ошибку

```
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grace-pro-android-main\app\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest47979618886500457.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
    C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grace-pro-android-main\app\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest47979618886500457.xml:34:9-40:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\grace-pro-android-main\app\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest47979618886500457.xml:41:9-47:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

Я понимаю что речь идет о том что в манифесте exported нет в параметрах, но это не в моем манифесте а в манифесте какой то библиотеке, но тут ничего не говориться что это за библиотека Если открыть манифест merge то там тоже нет ошибок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity` - указана же активность, по пакету можно догадаться, что это из андроид-тестов, вам нужно обновить версию `androidx.test.ext:junit:XXX`